# Kubernetes check serviceaccount permissions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When deploying a service via a Helm Chart, the installation failed because the `tiller` serviceaccount was not allowed to create a `ServiceMonitor` resource.

Note:

- `ServiceMonitor` is a CRD defined by the Prometheus Operator to automagically get metrics of running containers in Pods.
- Helm Tiller is installed in a single namespace and the RBAC has been setup using Role and RoleBinding.

I wanted to verify the permissions of the `tiller` serviceaccount.
`kubectl` has the `auth can-i` command, queries like these (see below) always return `no`.

- `kubectl auth can-i list deployment --as=tiller`
- `kubectl auth can-i list deployment --as=staging:tiller`

What is the proper way to check permissions for a serviceaccount?
How to enable the `tiller` account to create a ServiceMonitor resource?

Answer (score 125):

After trying lots of things and Googling all over the universe I finally found [this blogpost about Securing your cluster with RBAC and PSP](https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/securing-with-rbac-and-psp/#verifying-if-you-have-access) where an example is given how to check access for serviceaccounts.

The correct command is:
`kubectl auth can-i <verb> <resource> --as=system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccountname> [-n <namespace>]`

To check whether the `tiller` account has the right to create a `ServiceMonitor` object:
`kubectl auth can-i create servicemonitor --as=system:serviceaccount:staging:tiller -n staging`

Note: to solve my issue with the `tiller` account, I had to add rights to the `servicemonitors` resource in the `monitoring.coreos.com` apiGroup. After that change, the above command returned `yes` (finally) and the installation of our Helm Chart succeeded.

Updated `tiller-manager` role:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  labels:
    org: ipos
    app: tiller
  annotations:
    description: "Role to give Tiller appropriate access in namespace"
    ref: "https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#example-deploy-tiller-in-a-namespace-restricted-to-deploying-resources-only-in-that-namespace"
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups:
    - monitoring.coreos.com
  resources:
    - servicemonitors
  verbs:
    - '*'
```

Comment: `kubectl auth can-i` really helpful command for these kind of problems thanks

Comment: One common mistake of using `kubectl auth can-i` is forgetting add `-n <namespace>` for `rolebinding`, since the `rolebinding` only grants permission in a namespace.

Comment: `--list` is also useful to show all permissions for given account: `kubectl auth can-i --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default --list`

Answer (score 18):

this displays what permissions you have on a service account `prom-stack-grafana`:
e.g.

```
kubectl -n monitoring auth can-i \
     --list --as=system:serviceaccount:monitoring:prom-stack-grafana
```

Answer (score 9):

Note: `kubectl auth can-i` command has an edge case / gotcha / mistake to avoid worth being aware of.
Basically a user can be named with a similar syntax to a service account, and it can trick it.
It had me tripped up for quite a while so I wanted to share it.

```
alias k=kubectl
k create ns dev 
k create role devr --resource=pods --verb=get -n=dev 
k create rolebinding devrb --role=devr --user=system:serviceaccount:dev:default -n=dev # wrong syntax 
k auth can-i get pods -n=dev --as=system:serviceaccount:dev:default  # right syntax
# yes
```

(The fact that k auth can-i said yes made me think my rolebinding was correct syntax, but it's wrong)

This is correct:

```
k delete ns dev
k create ns dev 
k create role devr --resource=pods --verb=get -n=dev 
k create rolebinding devrb --role=devr --serviceaccount=dev:default -n=dev # right syntax 
k auth can-i get pods -n=dev --as=system:serviceaccount:dev:default  # right syntax
# yes
```

Here is visual proof of how it's wrong:

```
k create rolebinding devrb1 --role=devr --user=system:serviceaccount:dev:default -n=dev --dry-run=client -o yaml | grep subjects -A 4
# subjects:
# - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
#   kind: User
#   name: system:serviceaccount:dev:default

k create rolebinding devrb2 --role=devr --serviceaccount=dev:default -n=dev --dry-run=client -o yaml | grep subjects -A 4
# subjects:
# - kind: ServiceAccount
#   name: default
#   namespace: dev
```

If ever in doubt about syntax for imperative rbac commands, here's a fast way to look it up:

1. kubernetes.io/docs
2. search "rbac"
3. control+f "kubectl create rolebinding" on the page to get example of correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test live, create a kube config with your serviceAccount secrets. I've create the script above to do it automatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

function generate_sa() {
  local sa
  local namespace
  local context
  local target_namespace
  local output_file
  local "${@}"
  sa=${sa:?set sa}
  namespace=${namespace:?set namespace of the service account}
  context=${context:?set context}
  target_namespace=${target_namespace:? set target context namespace}
  output_file=${output_file:-/tmp/kube.conf}

  cluster=$(kubectl config view -o yaml | yq '.contexts.[] | select ( .name == "'"${context}"'") | .context.cluster')
  if [ -z "${cluster}" ]; then
    echo "We didn't find the cluster from context ${context}"
    exit 1
  fi

  server=$(kubectl config view -o yaml | yq '.clusters.[] | select ( .name == "'"${cluster}"'") | .cluster.server')

  secret=$(kubectl get sa "${sa}" -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}' -n "${namespace}")
  ca=$(kubectl get secret/"${secret}" -o jsonpath='{.data.ca\.crt}' -n "${namespace}")
  token=$(kubectl get secret/"${secret}" -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' -n "${namespace}" | base64 --decode)

  cat <<EOF > "${output_file}"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: ${cluster}
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ${ca}
    server: ${server}
contexts:
- name: ${cluster}
  context:
    cluster: ${cluster}
    namespace: ${target_namespace}
    user: system:serviceaccount:${namespace}:${sa}
current-context: ${cluster}
users:
- name: system:serviceaccount:${namespace}:${sa}
  user:
    token: ${token}
EOF

echo >&2 "Now run: export KUBECONFIG=${output_file}"
}

generate_sa "${@}"
```

Then execute that, it will create a kubeconfig file.

```
generate_sa_config.sh \
  sa=service-account-name \
  namespace=namespace-of-service-account \
  context=kubernetes-cluster-context-name \
  target_namespace=namespace-of-context
```

Don't forget to `export KUBECONFIG` environment variable. Now it's like you are the real ServiceAccount and you can play with roles.