# Kubernetes service account default permissions

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, docker-desktop, kubernetes-security

I am experimenting with service accounts. I believe the following should produce an access error (but it doesn't):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-sa

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: test-sa
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: test-container
    command: [sh]
    args:
    - -ec
    - |
      apk add curl;
      KUBE_NAMESPACE="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace)";
      curl \
        --cacert "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
        "https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/$KUBE_NAMESPACE/services";
      while true; do sleep 1; done;
```

```sh
kubectl apply -f test.yml
kubectl logs test-pod
```

What I see is a successful listing of services, but I would expect a permissions error because I never created any `RoleBinding`s or `ClusterRoleBinding`s for `test-sa`.

I'm struggling to find ways to list the permissions available to a particular SA, but according to [Kubernetes check serviceaccount permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889458/kubernetes-check-serviceaccount-permissions), it should be possible with:

```sh
kubectl auth can-i list services --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test-sa
> yes
```

Though I'm skeptical whether that command is actually working, because I can replace `test-sa` with any gibberish and it still says "yes".

---

According to the documentation, service accounts by default have ["discovery permissions given to all authenticated users"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions). It doesn't say what that actually means, but from more reading I found this resource which is probably what it's referring to:

```sh
kubectl get clusterroles system:discovery -o yaml
> [...]
> rules:
> - nonResourceURLs:
>   - /api
>   - /api/*
> [...]
>   verbs:
>   - get
```

Which would imply that all service accounts have `get` permissions on all API endpoints, though the "nonResourceURLs" bit implies this wouldn't apply to APIs for resources like services, even though those APIs live under that path… (???)

---

If I remove the `Authorization` header entirely, I see an access error as expected. But I don't understand why it's able to get data using this empty service account. What's my misunderstanding and how can I restrict permissions correctly?

Comment: can you share output of `kubectl get role,rolebinding -n default` and `kubectl get clusterrole,clusterrolebinding`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu first command returns "No resources found in default namespace". Second returns a large list including `clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/admin`, `clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:service-controller` and `clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:service-controller` among many others. Anything in particular from that output you want to know about?

Comment: Did you by any chance created a clusterrolebinding to bind this service account to `cluster-admin` clusterrole?

Comment: If it helps: this is a local test deploy of kubernetes using Docker's built-in "Enable Kubernetes" option. I believe is has no custom config. And for what it's worth, running `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep authorization-mode` shows that the access control modes are `Node,RBAC`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I highly doubt it; that doesn't seem like the kind of thing that would easily happen by accident! How can I definitively tell? Might be worth noting that the `test-sa` service account is freshly-made — I can change the name of it and run the `apply` again and see the same effect, so I don't think this is related to any silly state on that resource.

Comment: I just tried the same yaml in my kubeadm cluster and got a 403 error which is expected

Comment: I'll ask some colleagues to try it in various environments. Maybe it's something about the way docker desktop bundles kubernetes?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu a colleague helped me find `clusterrolebinding docker-for-desktop-binding` which is adding `cluster-admin` to `system:serviceaccounts` (?!). So it seems it is indeed a docker desktop thing.

Comment: Raised https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4774 - turns out this was already recognised as a bug in docker desktop for mac but they fixed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in Docker Desktop for Mac's Kubernetes support.

It automatically adds a `ClusterRoleBinding` giving `cluster-admin` to **all service accounts** (!). It only *intends* to give this to service accounts inside the `kube-system` namespace.

It was originally raised in [docker/for-mac#3694](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3694) but fixed incorrectly. I have raised a new issue [docker/for-mac#4774](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4774) (the original issue is locked due to age).

A quick fix while waiting for the bug to be resolved is to run:

```sh
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: docker-for-desktop-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: system:serviceaccounts:kube-system
EOF
```

I don't know if that might cause issues with future Docker Desktop upgrades but it does the job for now.

With that fixed, the code above correctly gives a 403 error, and would require the following to explicitly grant access to the services resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: [services]
  verbs: [get, list]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-sa-service-reader-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: service-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
```

---

A useful command for investigating is `kubectl auth can-i --list --as system:serviceaccount`, which shows the rogue permissions were applying to *all* service accounts:

> ```
> Resources                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
> *.*                             []                  []               [*]
>                                 [*]                 []               [*]
> [...]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The same bug exists in Docker-Desktop for Windows.

> It automatically adds a ClusterRoleBinding giving cluster-admin to all service accounts (!). It only intends to give this to service accounts inside the kube-system namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Docker Desktop by default a clusterrolebinding `docker-for-desktop-binding` gives `cluster-admin` role to all the service accounts created.

For more details check the issue [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4774)