# Setting up a Kubernetes Cronjob: Cannot get resource "horizontalpodautoscalers" in API group "autoscaling" in the namespace "staging"

Tags: kubernetes, roles, kubernetes-cronjob

I've tried to setup a cron job to patch a horizontal pod autoscaler, but the job returns `horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "my-web-service" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:staging:sa-cron-runner" cannot get resource "horizontalpodautoscalers" in API group "autoscaling" in the namespace "staging"`

I've tried setting up all the role permissions as below:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: staging
  name: cron-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: ["autoscaling"]
  resources: ["horizontalpodautoscalers"]
  verbs: ["patch"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: cron-runner
  namespace: staging
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-cron-runner
  namespace: staging
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cron-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cron-runner
  namespace: staging
---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scale-up-job
  namespace: staging
spec:
  schedule: "16 20 * * 1-6"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cron-runner
          containers:
          - name: scale-up-job
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl patch hpa my-web-service --patch '{\"spec\":{\"minReplicas\":6}}'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

`kubectl auth can-i patch horizontalpodautoscalers -n staging --as sa-cron-runner`  also returns `no`, so the permissions can't be setup correctly.

How can I debug this? I can't see how this is setup incorrectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes check serviceaccount permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889458/kubernetes-check-serviceaccount-permissions)

Comment: Hmm how would that apply to the above?...I've done all that as far as I can see

Comment: It's the way how you're asking for. --as=system:serviceaccount:staging:sa-cron-runner. I guess this is what you're looking for. The alternative to ask for on verb is to get the whole list like kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:staging:sa-cron-runner. But i see now in your output that it already uses the correct serviceaccount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the cronjob needs to first get the resource and then `Patch` the same. So, you need to explicitly specify the permission to `get` in the `Role` spec.

The error also mentions authentication problem with getting the resource:

```
horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "my-web-service" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:staging:sa-cron-runner" cannot get resource "horizontalpodautoscalers" in API group "autoscaling" in the namespace "staging"
```

Try modifying the `verbs` part of the `Role` as:

```
verbs: ["patch", "get"]
```

You could also include `list` and `watch` depending on the requirements in the scripts that is run inside the cronjob.

Comment: Could be _a_ problem, but don't think that's the auth problem. `kubectl auth can-i patch horizontalpodautoscalers -n staging --as sa-cron-runner ` still returns no.

Comment: try using like: `kubectl auth can-i patch horizontalpodautoscalers -n staging --as system:serviceaccount:staging:sa-cron-runner`

Comment: After adding this, and using the command Krishan suggested, it worked!