# Deploy Jenkins in EKS cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have a running EKS cluster and deployed the web application in the default namespace, now I'm trying to install Jenkins using k8s manifest file.

Here is list of files which I deployed, when I'm trying to configure Kubernetes cloud in manage Jenkins - configured system I'm not able to validate the test connection.

Note: I'm trying to configure Jenkins using the service account method.

rbac.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["ingresses"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
```

[image: Jenkins test connction]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

For service account `"system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins"` to have access to list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "jenkins", change your RoleBinding to:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
```

You can use [kubectl auth can-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889458/kubernetes-check-serviceaccount-permissions) command to test if the service account has access to perform a required function after applying the RoleBinding.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, what would be the value of the Kubernetes URL i have to use the default one or Kubernetes control plane is running at https://6F399196.er7.us-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com

Comment: I wouldn't explicitly know for Jenkins but I reckon it should the AWS generated Cluster ARN.

Comment: got i, let me apply my ARN inside the service account file then I will update you shortly

Comment: i verified the API i can success response, but still i'm getting same error

Comment: Can you update the screenshot please and the command you used to verify the access?

Comment: i was already updated the value in above stack

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any updates in your original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233892/discussion-between-rockn-rolla-and-gowmi).